# By using the \begin{description} make the labels start on the same line

Tags: description

I want to make list od description by using \begin{description}
and align the long label on the same starting point.

```
\begin{description}[leftmargin= 1.27cm, labelwidth=6cm]
    \item[h_{\mathrm{obs}_i}] : the cleaned and corrected ISSH measurements of i\textsuperscript{th} along-track point..
    \item[i] : the index for every satellite pass's co-located observation point time series.
    \item[h_{0i}] : the averaged sea surface heights of i\textsuperscript{th} along-track point.
    \item[h_{1i} t_j] : the trend part (linear sea level change).
    \item[h_{2i}cos(\omega_1 \cdot t_j)+h_{3i}sin(\omega_1 \cdot t_j)] : annual ocean variability signals.
    \item[h_{4i}cos(\omega_2 \cdot t_j)+h_{5i}sin(\omega_2 \cdot t_j)] : semiannual ocean variability signals.
    \item[\omega_1 \; \text{and}\;\omega_2] : the angular frequencies for annual and semiannual variations $\omega_1 = 2\pi/12$ and $\omega_2=2\pi/6$ respectively.
    \item[t_j] : the time difference between observation and reference epoch time $t_j=t_i-t_0$.
    \item[s] : the number of the selected satellite missions,
    \item[b_k] : the bias term, $k = (1, 2, 3, \cdots, s)$. 
    \end{description}
```

My code produces the following result:

[image]

However, I want the following result:

[image]

Comment: Please extend your example to a full but minimal example. Then it is a lot easier for others to test and suggest solutions. Have you looked in the `enumiem` manual? (you might want to tag the question with `enumitem` as it is clearly related.

Comment: You could also use a `tabular` environment for this.

Comment: I'd not use the colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @daleif said, please provide a full MWE.

You can do this by setting `leftmargin` properly. This is what I do in the following lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,mathtools}

\newlength\mylabelwidth
\setlength\mylabelwidth{6cm}
\newlength\myleftmargin
\settowidth\myleftmargin{: }
\addtolength\myleftmargin\mylabelwidth
\addtolength\myleftmargin\labelsep

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}[leftmargin=\myleftmargin, labelwidth=\mylabelwidth]
        \item[$h_{\mathrm{obs}_i}$]: the cleaned and corrected ISSH measurements of i\textsuperscript{th} along-track point..
        \item[$i$] : the index for every satellite pass's co-located observation point time series.
        \item[$h_{0i}$] : the averaged sea surface heights of i\textsuperscript{th} along-track point.
        \item[$h_{1i} t_j$] : the trend part (linear sea level change).
        \item[$h_{2i}\cos(\omega_1 \cdot t_j)+h_{3i}\sin(\omega_1 \cdot t_j)$] : annual ocean variability signals.
        \item[$h_{4i}\cos(\omega_2 \cdot t_j)+h_{5i}\sin(\omega_2 \cdot t_j)$] : semiannual ocean variability signals.
        \item[$\omega_1 \; \text{and}\;\omega_2$] : the angular frequencies for annual and semiannual variations $\omega_1 = 2\pi/12$ and $\omega_2=2\pi/6$ respectively.
        \item[$t_j$] : the time difference between observation and reference epoch time $t_j=t_i-t_0$.
        \item[$s$] : the number of the selected satellite missions,
        \item[$b_k$] : the bias term, $k = (1, 2, 3, \cdots, s)$. 
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

I want to add that I do not like the colons in your description a lot. As your description is typeset in justification, spaces can be enlarged, such that you will not have each line perfectly aligned, see second to last row: "the" is more to the right than "missions".

[image: Result]

Therefore I recommend to drop the colons and change my length specification to

```
\newlength\mylabelwidth
\setlength\mylabelwidth{6cm}
\newlength\myleftmargin
\setlength\myleftmargin{\dimexpr\mylabelwidth+\labelsep\relax}
```

Comment: Please change `cos` and `sin` to `\cos` and `\sin`, respectively.

Comment: @Mico Done, thanks for notifying. Obviously I did not read OP's code thoroughly enough.